# flutter:Converting simple html to TextSpan

Tags: html, flutter

I'm trying to convert simple html pages to flutter TextSpan using the following code:

```
TextSpan buildRichTextFromHtml(String html) {
  debugPrint(html);
  // Define the style for each element in the HTML tree
  TextStyle defaultStyle =
      const TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: PdfColors.black);
  TextStyle boldStyle = TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  TextStyle italicStyle = TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic);
  TextStyle underlineStyle =
      const TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline);

  // Create a stack to keep track of the nested elements
  List<InlineSpan> stack = [];

  // Create a helper function to handle each element encountered
  void handleElement(dom.Element element) {
    TextStyle currentStyle = defaultStyle;
    debugPrint('Merging ${element.localName} element :${element.innerHtml}. '
        'Nodes: ${element.nodes.length}');
    if (element.localName == 'b' || element.localName == 'strong') {
      // debugPrint('Merging <b> element');
      currentStyle = currentStyle.merge(boldStyle);
    } else if (element.localName == 'i' || element.localName == 'em') {
      // debugPrint('Merging <i> element');
      currentStyle = currentStyle.merge(italicStyle);
    } else if (element.localName == 'u') {
      // debugPrint('Merging <u> element');
      currentStyle = currentStyle.merge(underlineStyle);
    } else if (element.localName == 'h1') {
      currentStyle = currentStyle.copyWith(
        fontSize: defaultStyle.fontSize! * 2.7,
      );
    } else if (element.localName == 'h2') {
      currentStyle = currentStyle.copyWith(
        fontSize: defaultStyle.fontSize! * 1.9,
      );
    } else if (element.localName == 'h3') {
      currentStyle = currentStyle.copyWith(
        fontSize: defaultStyle.fontSize! * 1.5,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      );
    } else if (element.localName == 'br') {
      debugPrint('Merging <br> element');
      stack.add(const TextSpan(text: '\n'));
      return;
    } else if (element.localName == 'p') {
      // Add line breaks before and after the paragraph
      if (stack.last.toPlainText().endsWith('\n\n')) {
      } else if (stack.last.toPlainText().endsWith('\n')) {
        stack.add(const TextSpan(text: '\n'));
      } else {
        stack.add(const TextSpan(text: '\n\n'));
      }
      // Handle child elements within the <p> element
      List<InlineSpan> children = [];
      for (var childNode in element.nodes) {
        if (childNode is dom.Element) {
          handleElement(childNode);
        } else if (childNode is dom.Text) {
          children.add(TextSpan(
            text: childNode.text,
            style: currentStyle,
          ));
        }
      }

      // Add the paragraph as a single TextSpan
      stack.add(TextSpan(children: children));
      stack.add(const TextSpan(text: '\n\n'));
      return;
    }

    // Create a TextSpan for the current element
    TextSpan textSpan = TextSpan(
      text: element.text,
      style: currentStyle,
    );

    // Handle different types of list elements
    if (element.localName == 'ul') {
      // debugPrint('Handling <ul> bullets');
      final bulletSpans = element.children.map((liElement) {
        return TextSpan(
          text: '\t- ${liElement.text}\n',
          style: currentStyle,
        );
      }).toList();
      stack.add(TextSpan(children: bulletSpans));
    }
    // Check if the element is an ordered list (ol)
    else if (element.localName == 'ol') {
      // debugPrint('Handling <ol> numberings');
      int index = 1;
      final numberSpans = element.children.map((liElement) {
        final span = TextSpan(
          text: '\t$index. ${liElement.text}\n',
          style: currentStyle,
        );
        index++;
        return span;
      }).toList();
      stack.add(TextSpan(children: numberSpans));
    } else {
      // debugPrint('Handling ${element.localName} element');
      // Add the current element to the parent element
      if (stack.isNotEmpty) {
        InlineSpan parent = stack.last;
        if (parent is TextSpan) {
          // If the parent is a TextSpan, add the current element as its child
          stack.last = TextSpan(
            text: parent.text,
            style: parent.style,
            children: [...parent.children ?? [], textSpan],
          );
        } else if (parent is WidgetSpan) {
          // If the parent is a WidgetSpan, replace it with a RichText
          stack.removeLast();
          stack.add(TextSpan(children: [textSpan]));
        }
      } else {
        stack.add(textSpan);
      }
    }
  }
```

However while processing nested elements like  or  inside a

element, the text is getting duplicated or mixed up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the issue with nested elements like `<b>` or `<i>` inside a `<p>` element is that you are not resetting the `currentStyle` to `defaultStyle` for each child element within the `<p>` element. As a result, the style of the previous element is being carried over to the subsequent elements.

To fix this issue, you need to reset the `currentStyle` to `defaultStyle` for each child element inside the `<p>` element.